Question Preview does not match how the question looks on site when asked
This is with regards to this specific question.
On site it looks like this -

But in the edit preview it looks like this -

There is a distinct mismatch between what is shown as a preview and what is shown on site which seems to be connected to how tables are rendered.

long standing issue with the tables. Typically you need to add extra blank lines before/after them. Yet, the preview doesn't need them.

@VLAZ ahh thank you for informing me, first time I actually ran into it, any specific reason as to why the preview seems to be able to render without issue but the actual question does not format properly ?

¯\_(ツ)_/¯ different markdown renderers or something. There have been other mismatches in the past. Maybe there still are. But the tables are a huge problem, other mismatches might be negligible.
